# want to hide/show navbar when scroll down/up using js or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I simply want to hide navbar when scroll down and show when scroll up so i am adding what i have done but i am unable to acheive it, thanks in advance :)

my html code for navbar

```
<div class="nav-scroll">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
            </button>
             <img src="/cmm/images/codemymobile-logo-light.svg">
          </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#myPage">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
              <li><a href="#band">OUR EXPERTISE</a></li>
              <li><a href="#tour">PROCESS</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">SERVICE</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">CASE STUDIES</a></li>
              <li class="qoute-btn"><a href="#contact">GET A QUOTE</a></li>


            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

my  js is as follows

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("nav-scroll").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nav-scroll").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

Comment: where is u r css code ?if you want get perfect solution for u r question upload css files also

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first issue in your solution is that you have a class (`<div class="nav-scroll">`), but you are using `document.getElementById()`. You should use an id in your HTML () or use `document.getElementsByClassName()[0]` in your JavaScript.

Your question is flagged with jquery, but your code uses pure JavaScript. Below you can see a version of your code with minor changes to help you to make progress:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;

  // 20 is an arbitrary number here, just to make you think if you need the prevScrollpos variable:
  if (currentScrollPos > 20) {
    // I am using 'display' instead of 'top':
    document.getElementById("nav-scroll").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nav-scroll").style.display = "initial";
  }
}
```

After playing a bit with your own solution, you could try to move to jQuery. Here is a link that can be helpful:

https://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/fnCKE

Comment: @Saulotoldeo thank you for the solution, but i want to ask why on scrolling up i am not able to see the navbar back:)

Comment: @Avinash Could you create a codepen (https://codepen.io/pen/) to show your problem?

Comment: Because lastScrollPosition isn't defined! So it's still further than 20px when you scroll back

Comment: I think intersection observer would be better solution rather than firing function at each scroll?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a suggestion:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  var banner = $('.banner');
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (st > lastScrollTop){
      banner.addClass('hide');
    } else {
      banner.removeClass('hide');
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
  }, 100);
});
```

https://codepen.io/marcelo2605/pen/BXQVOO

Answer (score 4):

check out this:

```
document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
```

In the above line -50px indicates the height of the navbar if you want to hide the navbar then you have do -50px. If your navbar height is 90 then use -90.

And one important thing is that your nav must contain  id as navbar(i.e id="navbar")
Because in javascript you are accessing that id and reducing -50px;

```js
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px;margin-top:30px;">
  <p><b>This example demonstrates how to hide a navbar when the user starts to scroll the page.</b></p>
  <p>Scroll down this frame to see the effect!</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using CSS to handle the animation as CSS design for it and has, therefore, better performance

Start by adding an event listener to the scroll event of the browser, and then use Document method [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find the navigation bar with a CSS selector, then use the [classList property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add or remove a class from the element.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 50) {
      return document.querySelector('.navbar').classList.add('hide')
  }
  return document.querySelector('.navbar').classList.remove('hide')

});
```

You could even simplify it further by using a [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to handle the class changes, but it could feel less readable to some.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
   const navbar = document.querySelector('.header-main')      

   navbar.classList[window.scrollY > 50 ? 'add' : 'remove']('hide')

});
```

Then you could add [transition property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to animation via CSS for when you want to hide the navbar.

```css
.navbar {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar.hide {
   top: -50px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

`window.addEventListener('scroll', callback);`

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
let prevScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
const handleScroll = () => {
  if (process.browser) {
    const currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    const visible = prevScrollPos > currentScrollPos;
    prevScrollPos = currentScrollPos;
    // here add a class to your navbar
  }
}
```

For hiding navbar you can add this class to it.

```
.navbar {
  // actual navbar that has "navbar" class.
  transition: all .3s; // with this navbar will hide with smooth animation.
}
.navbar-hidden {
  top: -200px !important;
}
```

`note: if you are using react, keep on reading:`

In where you are adding event listener, do this instead:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  };
}, []);
```

and your callback should look like this:

```
const [navVisible, setNavVisible] = useState(true);
let prevScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
const handleScroll = () => {
  const currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  const visible = prevScrollPos > currentScrollPos;
  prevScrollPos = currentScrollPos;
  if (navVisible !== visible) setNavVisible(visible);
};
```

And in your jsx code, toggle .navbar-hidden class based on the value of navVisible state.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using `style.display = "none";` as in your example or the accepted answer, it would be better to use `.classList.add('hide')` and combine that with media queries to get get a good result on mobile as well.

For example:

```
// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, slide down the navbar
window.onscroll = function () {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.querySelector('.masthead').classList.remove('hide')
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.masthead').classList.add('hide')
  }
};
```

And the CSS style:

```
  @media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .hide{
        top: -50px;
    }    
}
```