# Sticky nav bar re-appears when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to create a bit of functionality where if the user scrolls down, the sitcky nav bar header will disappear. If the user scrolls up, it will re-appear.

I have almost got it, only issue is that when I scroll, the header disappears and only re-appears when I stop scrolling. Actually it sort of flickers before it re-appears.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_hide_scroll.asp

HTML:

```
<header id="site-header" class="header-footer-group sticky-element-original element-is-sticky" role="banner" style="margin-top: 0px !important; margin-left: 0px !important; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 651px; padding: 0px; z-index: 99999;">

...

</header>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
/* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("site-header").style.top = "0";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("site-header").style.top = "-100%";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Check out the runnable stack-snippet here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57235230/want-to-hide-show-navbar-when-scroll-down-up-using-js-or-jquery

Comment: The code you gave doesn't show the problem. Please provide more code.

Comment: You are updating `prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;` on each scroll event You may need a clearTimeout/setTimeout to update that... To buffer the events a bit. Scroll is a machinegun. ;)

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov I can't see any other code that would affected it other than wha I posted :)

Answer (score 1):

The scroll event is a machine gun.... It fires like 10+ times on a single mousewheel spin.

Try buffering those event a bit... With a combination of `clearTimeout`/`setTimeout`:

```js
/* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */

let scrollTimeout

var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("site-header").style.top = "0";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("site-header").style.top = "-100%";
  }

  // Event buffering here
  clearTimeout(scrollTimeout)
  scrollTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
  },500) // This delay may need adjustment...
}
```

```css
#site-header{
  background: yellow;
}

#page{
  height: 50000px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header id="site-header" class="header-footer-group sticky-element-original element-is-sticky" role="banner" style="margin-top: 0px !important; margin-left: 0px !important; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 651px; padding: 0px; z-index: 99999;">

I'm the header... I know I'm ugly, but that is just a demo.

</header>

<div id="page"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I did give this code a try and scrolling up works perfect, but scrolling down is the issue. Well it's not scrolling down that's the issue, it's when I stop after scrolling down that the nav bar re-appears (or shall I say flicker when it appears). I will quickly try to do that delay adjustment you mentioned in the code.

Comment: Damn didn't work with the time adjustment and I tried shorter and longer, 100, 5000 and 50000

Comment: I made it a snippet... Seems to work here.

Comment: You have a couple classes: `header-footer-group sticky-element-original element-is-sticky`.. Is that Bootstrap or something else?

Comment: Try removing those classes one by one. They may be used to trigger some other script.

Comment: Sorry went to sleep as it wasd 1am my side, they are related to a wordpress plugin for sticky header those classes. I will do what you said and remove them to see if any of those have an affect :)